# c#.net regex to remove certain non ascii chars does not work

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, ssis

I'm newbie to .net, I use script task in SSIS. I am trying to load a file to Database that has some characters like below. This looks like a data copied from word where - has turned to –

Sample text: 
Correction – Spring Promo 2016

Notepad++ shows:
[image: Sample text]

I used the regex in .net script `[^\x00-\x7F]` but even though it falls in the range it gets replaced. I do not want these characters be altered. What am I missing here?

If I don't replace I get a truncation error as I believe these characters take more than a bit size.

**Edit:** I added sample rows. First two rows have problem and last two are okay.

```
123|NA|0|-.10000|Correction – Spring Promo 2016|.000000|gift|2013-06-29
345|NA|1|-.50000|Correction–Spring Promo 2011|.000000|makr|2012-06-29
117|ER|0|12.000000|EDR - (WR) US STATE|.000000|TEST MARGIN|2016-02-30
232|TV|0|.100000|UFT / MGT v8|.000000|test. second|2006-06-09
```

After good long weekend :) I am beginning to think that this is due to code page error. The exact error message when loading the flat file is as below.

Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "NAME" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

This is what I do in my ssis package.

1. Script task that validates the flat files.

   - The only validation that affect the contents of the file is to check the number of delimited columns in the file is same as what it should be for that file. I need to read each line (if there is an extra pipe delimiter (user entry), remove that line from the file and log that into custom table).
   - Using the StreamWriter class, I write all the valid lines to a temp file and rename/move the file at the end.
   - apologies but I have just noticed that this process changes all such lines above to something like this.

> Notepad: Correction � Spring Promo 2016

How do I stop my script task doing this? (which should be the solution)

If that's not easy, option 2 being..
My connection managers are flat file source and OLEDB destination. The OLEDB uses the default code page which is **1252**. If these characters are not a match in code page 1252, what should I be using? Are there any other workarounds without changing the code page?

Script task:

```
                        foreach (string file in files)... some other checks
                        {
                        var tFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                        using (StreamReader rFile = new StreamReader(file))
                        using (var swriter = new StreamWriter(tFile))
                        {
                         string line;
                            while ((line = rFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                NrDelimtrInLine = line.Count(x => x == '|') + 1;
                                if (columnCount == NrDelimtrInLine)
                                {
                                    swriter.WriteLine(line);
                                }
                               }}}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to see the context of your script task/component to ensure our assumptions align with yours

Comment: You could use `[\u{80}-\u{10ffff}]` to identify non-ascii, then replace them with _entities_, i.e. `&#`(decimal or xHEX)`;` if it will be html. Or, you could convert them to a Unicode string character, example your string becomes `Correction \u2013 Spring Promo 2016`. It all depends on what is rendering the display of the text. And you might consider using the `\Uxxxxxxxx` if you expect character greater than 0xFFFF. But, this would only apply to literals at say compile time.

Comment: Yes, first thing you should do is get the char code. Then you can proceed with the regular expression. Convert to hex or other entity representations and update the question.

Comment: Isn't replacing such characters throwing away data? When text is stored, uses an encoding for the character set being used. When it is read, you have to use the same encoding. It seems that the problem is that you're not doing that. If you are starting with a text file, then find out what the encoding is. Or, if you are starting with a Word files (particularly a .docx), use a .NET library (e.g., OpenXML) that reads the Word file directly.

Comment: Like @CodeConfident I am curious of if you want to replace them or not.  I suspect you don't want to replace them but you don't want your data to be truncated.  What that likely means is you need to correct your data types and potentially encoding.  If you post and example of what you want to do, e.g. a couple of records, type of delimiters etc. we can probably help you find ways you don't even need a script task for to import the data.

Comment: @billinkc thank you, I have made the updates to reflect my question exactly..

Comment: Thank you others, I updated my question which kinda changed from original post. (how not to make that happen :)) Awaiting your valuable inputs..

Comment: Thank you for the edits, seeing the data is helpful. Can you also edit your Script Component code into the question so we can see how you are using the regex, doing the replace, etc

Comment: @billinkc thanks, updated. Regex replace is an option I am thinking to use. the default encoding on streamreader and writer converts certain characters to somethink like ? as I outlined in my updates..

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you intend since "I do not want these characters to be altered" seems mutually exclusive with "they must be replaced to avoid truncation". I would need to see the code to give you further advice.

In general I recommend always testing your regex patterns outside of code first. I usually use http://regexr.com

If you want to match your special characters:
[image: Matching Your Special Characters]

If you want to match anything except your special characters:
[image: Matching Non-Special Characters]